# Pebble only accepts data for the first time

Tags: java, android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I have developed a pebble companion app for android and when I send data (Android app to pebble watch) to pebble for the first time, it is accepted/received and displayed on pebble watch correctly. But after I finish the session and try to send data again to pebble watch, then pebble fails to receive/accept it. Although the pebble app gets launched, but it does not accept the data. Adding up to the problem, there is no error log being displayed on the console.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? When you say "send data" do you mean via AppMessage?

Comment: yes, I am send data using "PebbleKit.sendDataToPebbleWithTransactionId(appContext, pebAppId, pdHead, 0);"

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that you have not received anything? Do you have logs in your `in_received` handler?

To debug this type of problem you need to make sure that you have a log statement in your `appmessage_in_dropped` handler.

You can use [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150193/logging-enums-on-the-pebble-watch) to translate the error message to a readable string in the logs. [Full example here](https://github.com/sarfata/pbsat/blob/master/src/comm.c).